# NullPointerException при изменении текста в JTextArea

Tags: java

Нужно изменить текст в `JTextArea` при изменении текста в определенных (других) полях. Вызов метода, который вызывает метод изменения текста, проходит гладко, но само изменение текста вылетает с NPE. Я так понял, у меня не объявлен сам `JTextArea`. Но проблема в том, что он объявлен и прекрасно отрисовывается.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

*FormatterMain.java*:

```
private JTextArea FormattedTextView;

public static void main(String[]args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ...
            FormatterEngine formatterEngine = new FormatterEngine();
            ...
            JTextArea FormattedTextView = new JTextArea();
            FormattedTextView.setBorder(new MatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, (Color) SystemColor.textHighlight));
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(FormattedTextView);
            frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            FormattedTextView.setFont(textFont);
            FormattedTextView.setEnabled(false);
            FormattedTextView.setRows(10);
            ...
        }
    });
}

public void setTextInMainArea(String text) {
    this.FormattedTextView.setText(text);
}

....
```

*FormatterEngine.java*:

```
...
FormatterMain formatterMain = new FormatterMain();
...
public void refreshFinishedTextView(boolean Free) {
    ...
    formatterMain.setTextInMainArea("test"); //ошибка
    ...
}
```

Comment: Объявление локальной (внутри метода `run`) переменной `FormattedTextView` я вижу. Объявление глобальной переменной (поля) `FormattedTextView` я не вижу.

Comment: А самая первая строка не оно разве?

Comment: Согласен, точнее будет так: инициализации поля "нормальным" значением нет. После строки `private JTextArea FormattedTextView` в `FormattedTextView` находится `null`.

Comment: а что-то с этим можно сделать? Исправить или что-то

Comment: Да, `private JTextArea formattedTextView=new JTextArea();` А из run уберите. И еще, название переменных, объектов пишется с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Спасибо, только добавил static, а то среда ругалась

Answer (score 1):

```
FormatterEngine formatterEngine = new FormatterEngine();
...
FormattedTextView = new JTextArea(); // Тут надо было убрать JTextArea
FormattedTextView.setBorder(new MatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, (Color) SystemColor.textHighlight));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(FormattedTextView);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
FormattedTextView.setFont(textFont);
FormattedTextView.setEnabled(false);
FormattedTextView.setRows(10);
```

Comment: Я, может, чего-то не понимаю, но как в статическом методе `main` можно проинициализировать не статическое поле?

Comment: @Regent вы правы, так делать нельзя

Comment: Ну да, так нельзя. Стоит вынести в конструктор класса и вызывать уже объект класса